# Angular2 Protractor TypeError: this.flow_.getSchedulingFrame_ is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

Trying to run integration tests on an Angular2 app using protractor:

**protractor.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    'src/app/e2e/contact.e2e.js'
  ],
  framework: 'jasmine',
   useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

My test file: **contact.e2e.js**

```
describe('App', function(){
  it('should render the contact section', function() {
    browser.get('/');
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Message:
    Failed: this.flow_.getSchedulingFrame_ is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: this.flow_.getSchedulingFrame_ is not a function
        at promise.Promise.addCallback_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:651:16)
        at promise.Promise.then (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:592:15)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeThen_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1193:12)
        at ManagedPromise.resolve_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1147:16)
        at /Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1083:14
        at Task.Deferred.fulfill (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1432:7)
        at TaskQueue.onTaskComplete_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2995:26)
        at subQ.once (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2888:33)
        at TaskQueue.emit (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:64:21)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2882:12)
    From: Task: Run it("should render the contact section") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/src/app/e2e/contact.e2e.js:11:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/src/app/e2e/contact.e2e.js:10:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

My **package.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "~2.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.1.4",
        "angular2-express-engine": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
        "angular2-platform-node": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
        "angular2-universal": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
        "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "csurf": "^1.9.0",
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
        "flexslider": "^2.6.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "http-proxy": "^1.15.2",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
        "jquery.scrollto": "^2.1.2",
        "js.clone": "0.0.3",
        "methods": "~1.1.2",
        "modern-lru": "^1.0.8",
        "preboot": "~4.5.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "scrollspy": "^1.5.0",
        "velocity": "^0.7.2",
        "velocity-animate": "^1.3.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.6.26"
      },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "0.0.29",
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.29",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.3.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.32",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.0.33",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/mime": "0.0.28",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.35",
    "@types/serve-static": "^1.7.27",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jenkins-reporter": "0.0.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-jenkins-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.12.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.11",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.47.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.11",
    "webpack-merge": "~0.16.0",
    "webpack-s3-plugin": "^0.9.2"
  },
```

The weird thing is that it's only happening on my mac, when I'm running the tests via docker on my jenkins server it's running fine. 
Help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Update

My protractor is not global and the version of protractor that I'm running is: Version 4.0.14

Comment: Your package.json does not have a version of Protractor. Could it be that you are using a global installation of Protractor? Also, what version of Protractor is this?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to post my package.json dev dependencies. Protractor is not global and the version is 4.0.14.

Comment: So I still do not see a protractor version in your devDependencies. Also you are using @types/protractor. This is not required since Protractor supports TypeScript. Is this created by the angular cli?

Comment: There is a protractor in the dev dependencies: "protractor": "^4.0.11", You are right about the @types/protractor not needed, but even if it's removed it doesn't change the result

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of items to address:

**devDependencies**: Protractor 4.0.11 uses selenium-webdriver 2.53.1. It is unusual that you also have selenium-webdriver 2.47.0 as a devDependency in the project.

**the stacktrace**: The error `selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js` is suspect because `/lib/goog/` does not exist in the selenium-webdriver node module that Protractor uses in ^4.0.11. I suspect you are using an old version of Protractor.

- Protractor 4.0.11 uses selenium-webdriver 2.53.1 - does not have `lib/goog/`
- Protractor 2.5.1 uses selenium-webdriver 2.47.0 - **does have a folder have `lib/goog/`**
- Protractor 1.8.0 uses selenium-webdriver 2.44.0 - does have a folder `lib/goog/`

I would check how you are running Protractor. I think you are running it from a global context and should try `protractor --version` to verify.

Also helpful is to add scripts to your package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "protractor some/path/to/conf.js"
  }
```

Then execute this with `npm run e2e`. This will ensure that you are using protractor from your project node_modules in the project.

**Update:**

The answer stated above, I changed that 2.47.0 does have the path `/lib/goog/`. It was really late at night that I answered it and might have written that incorrectly. This is probably because I did an `npm i -S selenium-webdriver@^2.47.0`. Somehow you have stated you want ^2.47.0 however if you are shrinkwrapping 2.47.0 then that would prevent the carrot to download the last minor version.

An improvement on the answer. The stack trace below references two different versions of selenium-webdriver. The selenium-webdriver that is part of Protractor and a different version. The selenium-webdriver not in Protractor is referring to the path `lib/goog/`.

```
at promise.Promise.addCallback_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:651:16)
        at promise.Promise.then (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:592:15)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeThen_ (/Users/yarivkatz/Development/workspace/bugeez/bugeez-lp-final/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1193:12)
```

As stated above in the update, I believe there is something that is locking in your selenium-webdriver version. Also, because you have two versions of selenium-webdriver, you are calling the `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver` and somehow that is calling a `node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/`.

Please remove the devDependency, remove it from shrinkwrap, and reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I'm not running protractor from global context, the version is 4.0.14.  Thanks

Comment: Well you have two versions of selenium webdriver installed. One version has lib/goog/. I believe it is your other selenium webdriver. Your stack trace references two selenium webdrivers.